# Scanf and printf in 'for' loop simple code is not working

Tags: c

I am doing a game where user have to enter coordinates: `F5`, `H8`

For example.

I want to do this in a 'for' loop but it is working only for first time, further it is not working well. I'm looking for any advice.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int k,z,x;
char y;
int main()
{
    for(k=1;k<=10;k++)
    {
printf("Enter letter and digit\n");
    scanf("%c %d",&y,&x);
    printf("%c %d\n",y,x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your code, so that others can copy your code (easily) to help you

Comment: But again dont put image in code

Comment: `scanf` is hard to use in a case like this.  If the user enters something wrong (for example, letters when you expected `%d`), `scanf` can never get past it.

Comment: Scanf only working for the first time in a loop, sounds like the favorite "newline stuck in input needs to be handled/ignored".

Answer (score 0):

Simple mod:

```
scanf(" %c %d",&y,&x);
       ^
```

What's that space? A space in `scanf()` format string consumes and discards all whitespaces if present. So spaces, tabs and newlines won't bother anymore.

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p5)

> **A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read.** The directive never
>   fails.